# If $p=\lg 5$, express the following in terms of $p$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

If $p=\lg 5$, express the following in terms of $p$.

Express $\log_{5}2$ in terms of $p$.

=$\log_{5}2$

=$\frac{\log_{10}2}{\log_{10}5}$

=$\frac{\log_{10}2}{p}$

Then how to simplify it? My book's answer: $\frac{1}{p}-1$.

Comment: Instead of $\log_{10}$, try using $\lg$.

Comment: @JohnHabert What is the difference between $\log_{10}$ and $\lg$?

Comment: Generally I've seen $\lg$ used to stand for $\log_2$. But I have a lot of computer science background where that is the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{lg2}{lg5} = \frac{lg\frac{10}{5}}{lg5}=\frac{lg10-lg5}{lg5}=\frac{1-p}{p}=\frac{1}{p}-1$

Comment: How does $\lg2$ turn to $\lg\frac{10}{5}$?

Comment: Substitution because $2= \frac{10}{5}$.

Comment: This is necessary to use the logarithm rule $lg(\frac{a}{b})=lg(a)-lg(b)$

Comment: Oh...got it...:)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $log_{10}10$ = 1.

Use log identities, i.e. write $log_{10}2$ as $log_{10}\frac{10}5$ which is equal to $log_{10}10 - log_{10}5$ which is $1-p$ as required.